# Select only 1 child from each parent

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

One `Author` can have many `Book`. Table `Book` have `Author_Id` on it.

I Want a LINQ query that returns a `IQueryable<Book>` (So I can navigate with `Book.Author.Name` and stuff), but Only 1 Book per Author.

How do I do that with a LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is it:

```
var books = from a in authors
            from b in a.Books.Take(1)
            select b);
```

Edit: Less *hacky* way to do this:

```
var books = authors.Select(author => author.Books.First())
                   .Select(book => book);
```

Comment: This solution is actually better than mine and generates less SQL.

Comment: @Vince Panuccio That's a surpise as it feels quite "hacky" using `Take(1)`!

Comment: @VitorReis question specifies one book per author, it doesn't give any more information than that so I feel that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: I have to agree with @Vince Panuccio here, I think it's a question of the author not knowing what he wants (or not explaining it correctly).

Comment: @Vince Just out of curiosity, how do you view the generated SQL?

Comment: @aligray I use a tool called LinqPad

Answer (score 3):

```
var authorsWithFirstBook = 
    from book in Books
    group book by book.Author into authorBooks
    select authorBooks.First();
```

That should give you the first book in the group.

You should then be able to do

```
foreach (var book in authorsWithFirstBook) {

  Console.WriteLine(book.Author.FirstName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Vince, But as I said, I don't want to work with anonymous Types is there a way we could do it using the "Book" Type?

Comment: returns `IQueryable<Book>`. Exactly as OP asked :).

Comment: Yeah, I already had created a Specific class for the new type :)  thank you for the help

Comment: How do you guys know if `Books` relation is defined?